# Select SQL to pick next non matching record for same date

Tags: t-sql, psql

I have table name as `client_audit`, unique and identity column is `recno`, `clientcode`, `auditdate`, `Auditflag` and has other multiple columns which are tend to be change and recorded as before audit and after audit image for same client code.
`auditflag` 1 means before change and `auditflag` 2 is after change image.

If I run `select * from client_audit where audit_flag = 1` then record count is coming as 30000100

If I run `select * from client_audit where audit_flag = 2` then record count is coming as 30000000

So actually for 100 records I don't have after audit image.

Now records are getting created in pair like for same `clientcode` before and audit image will be created, their `recnumber` will be in sequence.

Is there any way from same table I can fetch those 100 record which only have before audit image and not after audit image considering `recno` as unique and identity and audit records will be in pair for same client code and for same `audidate`?

Comment: T-SQL is used by SQL Server, PSQL is used by PostgreSQL. Unless you are working with both these products, pleas pick the correct SQL dialect and remove the wrong tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your table structure correctly try this

```
select * from client_audit where audit_flag = 1 and clientcode not in (select clientcode from client_audit where audit_flag = 2)
```

Comment: Please note this audit table is massive it can have mutliple before and after audit entries for same client so I need to find entries where after audit record is missed.

Answer (score 0):

First, a free tip: If you are inserting both records to the database at the same time, you should use a transaction so that if one of the inserts fails, both of them will and you will not end up with orphan records like you do now.

To answer your question:
You can use not exists to get all the records where `audit_flag = 1` that don't have a corresponding record with `audit_flag = 2`, based on `clientcode` and `auditdate`, like this:

```
select * 
from client_audit as c1
where audit_flag = 1
and not exists
(
    select 1 
    from client_audit as c2
    where audit_flag = 2
    and c1.clientcode = c2.clientcode
    and c1.auditdate = c2.auditdate
)
```

Comment: Hello Zohar, thanks for your reply, does select inside not exists take audit_flag =1 or = 2 ?

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste typo. Of course it should be `audit_flag = 2`. Fixed.